# How i can access Sub-Entity attributes from Suber-Entity in Core data

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a super entity in core-data called element and has two sub entity called (IsBoolean,IsGrade) i try to access these sub-entity attribute from below code.I need your help about this issue

--------------------- Core data structure --------------------
Super Entity  [Element->elmentID]
Sub Entities [IsBoolean->value] + [IsGrade->value]

---------------------- brief code ----------------------------

```
NSFetchRequest *formRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *formEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Element" inManagedObjectContext:ManagedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *formDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"elementID" ascending:YES]; 
NSPredicate *formPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"elementID==%d",2];
[formRequest setPredicate:formPredicate];
[formRequest setEntity:formEntity]; 
[formRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:formDescriptor]]; 
[formRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];
resultController_= [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:formRequest managedObjectContext:ManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil  ];
resultController_.delegate =self;
for (Element *elementData in resultController_) {
        // I can access super entity attribute 
        NSlog(@"%@",elementData.elementID);

        // Here i can't access sub entity attribute from super entity 
        NSLog(@"%@",elementData.value);

}
```

Find the following screenshot for datamodel[image]

Comment: So your sub-entities also have a grade element ID of 2? This seems like an unusual structure, and calling an entity class a name like isBoolean is going to be very confusing. Also your code will crash (isn't it giving compiler warnings?) on elementData.value if your fetched object is just an Element as opposed to one of your sub-entities.

Comment: This is a brief code i wrote it here but not compiled , my problem is **How i can access sub entity attributes from super entity** is it doable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that sub-entities do not have to be sub-classes. The class hierarchy and entity hierarchy do *not* have to match. In most cases it will make sense to have them match, but there are use cases where that's not the case. In fact, not having them match may give you a lot of flexibility.

You can have an entity **book* with corresponding **Book** class, and an entity **author** with a corresponding **Author** class. In this case they would not have a common super-entity. But the classes may very well have a common super-class that defines and implements e.g. `@property NSString *name;` and `@property UIImage *image;` and related methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on amended question**

You ***will not have*** any instances of your sub-entities unless you have added managed objects to your context that are of the sub-entity.

Each sub-entity is equivalent to a subclass of your Element entity - so it will have the element attributes, plus the new attributes you have defined in the sub-entity. It will also inherit in class terms if you have made custom NSManagedObject subclasses.

To talk about accessing the properties of a sub-entity from within a super entity is missing the point.

To add instances of the sub-entity, you would just insert entities as you would any other managed object, using the sub-entity name.

---

*Original answer, 90% of which is still valid*

You're not trying to access them from a super entity, you're accessing them from whatever is doing your fetch request. In that case, if you check that your returned objects are of the appropriate class or have the relevant attributes, then yes.

But from within a super-entity, no, that doesn't make any sense. It's the same as class inheritance - you couldn't access `.text` from within a UIView just because UILabel is a subclass of it. But you could have a list of objects that were UIViews, check if one of them was in fact a UILabel, then access it's `.text` property.

For a fetch request returning a mix of entities and sub-entities, you'd do something like

```
if ([elementData.entity.name isEqualToString:@"IsBoolean"]) // means it is the isBoolean sub-entity
    NSLog(@"%@",elementData.value);
```

Slightly better, you would get the attributes dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = elementData.entity.attributesByName;
if ([attributes objectForKey:@"value"]) // Means there is an attribute called "value"
    NSLog(@"%@",elementData.value);
```

With the latter case the dictionary is full of NSAttributeDescription objects which tell you what kind of attribute you are dealing with. See the various core data class references ([NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html), [NSEntityDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html) and [NSAttributeDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer i agree with you .Could you please tell how i can access these attributes from fetched request data.Is there any additional code for the default fetched request.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work because the elementData is object of Element entity therefore will not enter the if case statement

Comment: If it is an Element entity then you shouldn't be able to access the value. Have you actually got any entities other than Elements in your managed object context?

Comment: No i fetched the Group entity which has 1-to-many relationship with Element entity and from the relationship get Element and i want to access the sub-entity .Any thing need to clarify your ambiguous i ready and many thanks for your corporation.

Comment: There aren't going to be any instances of your sub entities if you haven't created them. I'm not sure you have understood what sub-entities are for - they are like subclasses. So in your relationship there could be a mix of Element entities and the sub-entities, but the Element entity has nothing to do with the sub-entities, unless your element has a relationship which can contain sub-entities.

Comment: Really this is the first time i use sub-entity can i send to you my core-data model to see the relationship with Element (entity) .Could you please get me any sample code for inheritance entity and fetched and insert data to the core-data.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not a support desk ;). Add more information to your question - you can include screenshots of your model, for example.